# Convert list of class objects to list of lists

Tags: python, list, scope

My goal is to write a function, which receives a list of class objects and converts these into a list of lists, this is what I currently have:

```
def convertToListOfLists(toConvert):
    listOfLists = []
    temp = []
    for t in toConvert:
        temp.append(t.datenbestand)
        temp.append(t.aktenzeichen)
        temp.append(t.markendarstellung)
        temp.append(t.aktenzustand)
        listOfLists.append(temp)
        temp.clear()
    print(listOfLists)
    return listOfLists
```

Output: `[[], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], []]`
while 'toConvert' holding 17 objects

If I move the print into the loop and print out my 'listOfLists' I can see that the objects are added to my 'listOfLists' correctly but as you can see, if I access 'listOfLists' outside the loop, 'listOfLists' only holds empty lists.

What am I missing?

Comment: Mandatory link to [Ned Batchelder](https://nedbatchelder.com/text/names.html)

Comment: "temp.clear" would do that, just initialise temp inside of the loop

Comment: `return [[t.datenbestand, ...] for t in toConvert]`…

Comment: I think you need to deepcopy the temp list. You are appending only a reference to the list and then deleting it. Deepcopy is from a standard library.

Comment: @alanturing Yes, but that would be an overcomplicated workaround…

Comment: @deceze Ok, there is an answer that is bether than my solution. XD

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to make a new `temp` everytime through the loop:

```py
def convertToListOfLists(toConvert):
    listOfLists = []
    for t in toConvert:
        temp = []
        temp.append(t.datenbestand)
        temp.append(t.aktenzeichen)
        temp.append(t.markendarstellung)
        temp.append(t.aktenzustand)
        listOfLists.append(temp)
    print(listOfLists)
    return listOfLists
```